# "The file has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested"

Tags: web-services, iis, exception

I've installed a set of standard webservices on a Windows 2003, IIS 6 server. When I access anyone of the webservices through my browser I get a .NET yellow screen with the exception:

**The file '/SuperOfficeWebService/Contact.asmx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested.**

The same standard webservices (installed through an .msi) works on other machines.

The .asmx files only contain the text "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!", as expected.

In the bin\ subfolder I have the .compiled files which match the .asmx files.

What could be causing the error message? Any IIS settings, or .NET 2.0 settings which prevents IIS from loading the compiled files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing "Microsoft Web Service Enhancements v3.0".

It can be downloaded here: http://www.google.no/search?hl=no&q=microsoft+web+services+enhancements+3.0+download&cad=h

Comment: What do you mean by MS WS enhencements 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is still looking for a solution, I had the same problem. My issue was that I was using 'aspnet_compiler' from the wrong framework folder. My project was created in VS'05 and .net 2.0. I was attempting to precompile from "c:\windows\Microsoft .NET\Framework\v4.xxxx" when I needed to precompile from "c:...\v2.xxxx".

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message, but not w/a web service.  In my case, it was a vanilla ASP.NET 2.0 web app, that also happens to use AJAX Control Toolkit v1.0.61025.  When I tracked it down, I found my environment (VS or one of my addons) stripped two elements from my web.config:

- "assemblies" tag was missing two lines:

  ```
  <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  ```
- Also missing were these lines from "system.web" section:

  ```
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
  ```

I am doing XCOPY deployment and use web.config to control differences between development and live (connection string, etc).  After publishing in VS (to a folder on my dev box), I delete web.config (since it has my dev settings) and just keep using the same web.config in live.  Because the live web.config had these missing lines, I had been compiling against a web.config that was different by more than just a few app key values.

Restoring these lines in my dev environment and republishing fixed the issue.  Whoa, they've just disappeared again from my VS 2010, I better log a question!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by running the following command to reassociate the right compiler with IIS.

Go to the folder of the version of .NET you want to use (ie: `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`)

And run: `aspnet_regiis -i`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this problem when running an MSBuild script, chances are that your project is a 2.0 or 3.5 project and MSBuild is using the 4.0 compiler. Add `TargetFrameworkMoniker="3.5"` to your `AspNetCompiler` directives.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we have had this message after re-creating the site. The files on the site had to be compiled using .NET 4.0.3 and IIS default was 2.0.5.  We had to change the ASP.NET version in Site> Properties> ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Bin deploying Microsoft.WebServices3.dll 3.0.5305.0 worked for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 with .Net Framework 4.5+.  This option alleviates the need to install .Net Framework 3.5 and WSE 3.0.